# Should I choose Ubuntu Server when installing a custom WM?

Tags: server, window-manager, i3-wm

I would like to install the i3 Window Manager and when I tried it with the Unity version, some styles carried over to i3, which didn't look good. From my understanding the Server edition is just Ubuntu without X Server. Is that true? If yes, should I use that instead of the standard Ubuntu version? If not, is there a version of Ubuntu, which just does not have a WM, because there is no "i3buntu" per se.

Comment: Server or Desktop is just another/different selection of default packages - so if you want to start without X - starting with a server image isn't a bad way.

Comment: You could also consider Debian: https://www.debian.org/distrib/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the "minimal" or "netinstall" ISO, which will download and install only a core system, plus the packages you select. If I recall correctly, it does not include some of the more "server"-y stuff that Ubuntu Server includes. Since it downloads packages on-the-fly, there won't be a boatload of updates to install once you boot into your new system.

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso